# Instead of executing .php, Nginx is downloading file

Tags: nginx

Instead of executing .php, it's downloading.

I am trying to configure php7 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default looks like this.

Can anyone help?

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

            root /var/www/html;

            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
            server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

            location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
    }

    server {
            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
            # SSL configuration
            listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            include snippets/ssl-mydomain.com.conf;
            include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

            location /web {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:32400/web/;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your second server (ssl) block is missing the `location ~ \.php$` block. This is what tells nginx to execute the PHP rather than serve it raw.

In other words, give this a go:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        # SSL configuration
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        include snippets/ssl-mydomain.com.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location /web {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:32400/web/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You redirect all to https and your https server part doesn't handle PHP, see missing `fastcgi` configs.